# UpdatePanel driving me insane - Dynamicly Created UpdatePanel Problem

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

So, I have the following code in Page_Load:

```
updDesignations = new UpdatePanel();
updDesignations.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(toutLineDesignation);            
updDesignations.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;
updDesignations.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;            
divDesignations.Controls.AddAt(0,updDesignations);
```

When I click on a Linkbutton within this dynamically created update panel, the appropriate event handler is called on the server. However, any changes made are not persisted back to the client, and the HTTP response from the update panel AJAX call is always empty:

The request is properly formed, and includes the correct form submission information, the response is simply this:

```
Server  Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date    Tue, 07 Apr 2009 22:30:57 GMT
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store
Pragma  no-cache
Expires  -1
Content-Length  0
```

This is driving me nuts, as this has to be a dynamicly created update panel. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting an ID on this UpdatePanel.  UpdatePanels get angry when they don't have an ID.  I have solved many a weird problem with them just be ensuring they have an ID.

Comment: oooh! An Angry UpdatePanel! Does it also get angry when it's children trigger it? :P I know it's lame, but i'm tired and can't sleep :(